# Is there a convention for or list of Marshmallow mail User Agent Strings?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5

Build numbers are great UA strings are better. Is there a naming convention for or master list of Nexus native mail app UA strings?

Comment: Um, what exactly is "Nexus native mail app"?

Comment: @CommonsWare- If you want to use UA string to identify if an update has/not been installed using UA string(s), where do you find UA strings? From the nexus security bulletin: "We have released a security update to Nexus devices through an over-the-air (OTA) update. Builds LMY49F or later and Android 6.0 with Security Patch Level of January 1, 2016 or later address these issues. Refer to the Common Questions and Answers section for more details." great... what is the UA string for LMY49F?

Comment: "what is the UA string for LMY49F?" -- I am assuming that by "UA string", you mean a `User-agent` HTTP header sent by a Web browser. In that case, there is no "UA string for LMY49F". The choice of a `User-agent` header value is made by the Web browser. That's an app; LMY49F is a build of an operating system. There is no requirement that any of the many Android Web browsers include `Build.FINGERPRINT` (which I *think* is how an app would get `LMY49F`) as part of its `User-agent` header.